# Return String or 404 exception in asp .net web api core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, asp.net-core-webapi

My **ASP.NET CORE 3** web `Get` API is as follows:

```
        [HttpGet("{trxid}", Name = "Getca")]
        public async Task<string> Getca(string trxid)
        {
            try
            {
                var r = getEos();
                GetTransactionResponse result = await r.GetTransaction(trxid);
                string resultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.trx.trx.actions[0].data);
                return resultJson;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.ToString();
            }
        }
```

I need if the user provides incorrect `trxid` then throw 404 exception otherwise, return `result` in string format (as it is given in code). Currently, in this case, it throws the exception from `catch` but with `200 error code`. I want exception with 404 error code.

I tried :

```
return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound);
```

But then I need to change the API return data type, which I need string if data found.
Please help.

Comment: Short version: change the return type of your method to `ActionResult<string>`, then you can return either the string value or `NotFound()`.

Comment: `ActionResult`  is not supporting the `async` method.

Comment: Then use `Task<ActionResult<string>>`.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please post this as an answer?